# Remix Web3 Provider: Out of Gas - Ethereum Ganache and TestRPC

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I'm having an issue with ganache and testRPC where I keep getting an `out of gas` error only when using the web3 provider but not when using Javascript VM or from truffle javascript tests.

My mappings are set up like so:

```
mapping (uint => address) public reservers;
mapping (uint => Reservation) public reservations;

mapping (uint => address) public bidders;
mapping (uint => Bid) public bids;
mapping (uint => uint) public lastSoldFor;
```

And the method that throws a `VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas` is:

```
function sell(uint rId) public {
    reservations[rId].publicKey = bids[rId].publicKey;
    reservers[rId] = bidders[rId];
    lastSoldFor[rId] = bids[rId].price;

    delete bids[rId];
    delete bidders[rId];
}
```

If I comment out the two `delete` lines it runs successfully. However if I use `delete` or even if I simply re-assign them they fail.

When running this through Truffle's testing suite it works, and also when manually committing those actions through Remix using Javascript VM it works. Only when it's connected to testRPC or ganache does it fail.

Every other method seems to work fine from ganache as well, it only seems to have a problem with deletion. I've also seen some references to this being because gas is refunded and since the gas price of this method is fairly low it causes some weirdness in ganache. Is there a workaround for this which doesn't make me have to upload the contract to a test network each time I want to make changes?

---

Edit: It seems I can prove this is not related to low gas consumption but to clearing of mapping indexes. I added some massive gas consumption into the method and it still exits with the same out of gas error.

New state variable:

```
uint[] memorysink;
```

And then in the method I added

```
memorysink.push(200000000);
memorysink.push(200000000);
memorysink.push(200000000);
memorysink.push(200000000);
memorysink.push(200000000);
```

which took the gas consumption from `43279` to `141513` however it still provides the out of gas error.

Comment: It looks like you're hitting the gas refund issue. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38917/deleting-element-from-mapping-exceeds-gas-limit/38919#38919

Comment: @AdamKipnis Yeah that's the gist I was getting too, however I don't see any workarounds for the actual problem when travelling down the rabbit hole.

Comment: The problem manifests itself when you try to rely on `estimateGas` for the `gasLimit`, which is the default behavior if you don't provide it in your client. Just provide an adequate `gasLimit` when you initialize the transaction in your client.

Comment: Yup, I can confirm that adding 100k more gas to the transaction does in-fact force it to go through from MetaMask, however since there's no way to provide that in Remix it will always fail internally when using web3 provider.

Answer (score 0):

As @AdamKipnis has suggested we can get around the issue using a heightened gasLimit. This isn't currently possible from within Remix itself however specifying an additional 50-100k gasLimit from MetaMask when interacting with that method did indeed solve the problem and provide a work-around for the issue in it's current state. However, this is still just a band-aid and more in-depth tests will be needed to find a proper solution to the core issue.